Performance Issue with Multi-threading in VS Code Terminal
I am encountering a performance issue when working with multi-threaded code in the VS Code terminal. Here is the scenario:
I am running a multi-threaded application on an Amazon EC2 Windows instance with ample resources (24 CPUs/48 cores, high memory). However, when I terminate the threading session in my code, it takes an unusually long time for the terminal session in VS Code to reopen.
Here are the steps I have taken to troubleshoot:
Resource Utilization: I have monitored CPU and memory usage on the EC2 instance to ensure that they are within reasonable limits during code execution.
Terminal Configuration: I have reviewed my terminal configuration in VS Code to ensure that it is optimized for performance without any unnecessary extensions or configurations.
Despite these efforts, the delay in reopening the terminal persists, affecting my workflow efficiency. I am seeking guidance on potential solutions or further troubleshooting steps to address this issue.
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I am seeking guidance on potential solutions or further troubleshooting steps to address this issue.
Run my multithreading code efficiently and effectively.

Oops! Looks like you forgot to post your Minimal Reproducible Example

Have you tried to omit the VS Code and execute your code using the ordinary terminal?
